# I cannot see any output using Python in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying run a script in VSCode.  I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and get this output:

```
[Running] python -u "the_directory_of_file\the_file_I_use.py"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.191 seconds
```

I don't see my program's output. However, when I run the script from the terminal, it works correctly.  How do I get VSCode to display my program's output?

Comment: I don't see Ctrl+Alt+N in the [list of standard keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf). Is there an extension that you're using for Python?

Comment: Yes, I use the extension Code Runner. But even without the extension, by clicking the run button (triangle), I'm getting the same results.

Comment: What does your runner configuration look like in `.vscode/launch.json`? Please update your question with that info, not in the comments.

Comment: Press Ctrl + Shift + ` Keys on VSCode after finish coding. And run code with the instruction, ex : `python filename.py`.

Comment: I'm struggling here, because when I launch the Python Run/Debug, it launches it in the terminal. So I'm not able to re-create your issue

Comment: After looking at the extension [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) it appears to be at least consistent with the output OP is seeing. @doctorasgr, it appears that this extension has [quite a few bugs](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+python). maybe you should report this

Comment: @lionking-123 the combination doesn't work for me. It goes to terminal but it doesn't run the code. It only shows the destination of the file in the terminal.

Comment: Did you run the instruction on terminal? ex : `python filename.py` or `python3 filename.py`. In here, filename must be replaced with your python file name.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth I disabled the extension but still no output.

Comment: @lionking-123 yes, if I copy-paste the code in the terminal it runs okay. But I want something similar to what I was doing in RStudio where I could see the results of my code straight away.

Comment: @doctorasgr, the output that shows `[Running]` and `[Done]` is output from the Code Runner extension. if it's disabled, then Run and Debug should output to the Terminal, not to an extension output. maybe try re-loading the window after disabling?

Comment: Can you share your code and settings?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to install python **https://www.python.org/downloads/**.

After installing .exe file of python. Go to downloads where you have downloaded the .exe file, open it by double click on it.

[image]

it looks like above window. before click on INSTALL NOW click on **Add python 3.9.6 to PATH**.then install it.

Now, go to VS code and try your program.

Comment: If you don't mind can yiu please share the code of this file.